# How to force Flex Grid width?

Tags: html, css, angular, flexbox

In my Angular project, I have the following divs in an HTML page but due to some padding and margins, I have not managed to locate 2 div in one row. Similar problems are encountered using different size of flexgrid / flexbox and I need to be clarified how to force it? I do not want to horizontal scrollbar to be visible and I tried to set width as 100% for outer divs. Any help pls?

```
<div class="p-grid">
    <div class="p-col-6">
        <div class="" ></div>
    </div>

    <div class="p-col-6">
        <div class="" ></div>
    </div>

    <div class="p-col-6">
        <div class="" ></div>
    </div>

    <div class="p-col-6">
        <div class="" ></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: code example please?

Comment: If you can avoid IE/Edge(>16) I'd recommend just using [CSS grid proper](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please see below example.

```css
.p-grid{
border: 2px solid red;
padding: 10px;
display:flex;
flex-wrap: wrap; /* This will control child items from over flowing */
box-sizing: border-box;
}

.p-col-6{
box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 2px solid green;
  flex: 1 0 50%; /* For equal widths in columns */ 
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  max-width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="p-grid">
  <div class="p-col-6"> 
  </div>
  <div class="p-col-6"> 
  </div>
</div>

<h1> 
See below example for 4 divs in  two rows
</h1>

<div class="p-grid">
  <div class="p-col-6"> 
  </div>
  <div class="p-col-6"> 
  </div>
  <div class="p-col-6"> 
  </div>
    <div class="p-col-6"> 
  </div>
</div>
```

To force width, you can use `flex-basis:100%` property on .p-grid
In `g-col` use  `flex-grow:1` for equal columns width

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you can do if you need to keep your "gutter" at a fixed width (you can tweak the borders size on the items and the padding on the container to change it, you can also set the border to transparent so it doesn't interfere with a possible background you may have):

```css
.p-grid {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
}

.p-col-6 {
  border: 10px solid white;
  width: 50%;  
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="p-grid">
    <div class="p-col-6">
        <div class="" >
          <p>Some Content</p>          
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="p-col-6">
        <div class="" >
          <p>Some Content</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="p-col-6">
        <div class="" >
          <p>Some Content</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="p-col-6">
        <div class="" >
          <p>Some Content</p>          
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I used the Optimum's solution but this seems to be working also. So, voted up ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can add another class to `p-col-6` that overrides the width. Then just calculate 50% - padding in px. Something like

```
.p-col-6.padding-override{
   width: calc(50% - 10px);//if your total right & left padding was 10px on the child div
}



<div class="p-grid">
    <div class="p-col-6 padding-override">
         <div class="" ></div>
    </div>

    <div class="p-col-6 padding-override">
        <div class="" ></div>
    </div>

    //etc...
```

Comment: Perfect solution, simple and easy to apply. Many thanks Sean Paul.